# [sys].[dm_db_index_usage_stats] returns more entries in some databases

Tags: sql-server-2012, index, dmv

I am using the following query to get some indexes usage statistics:

```
SELECT DB.[name]
      ,OBJECT_NAME(IDX.[object_id]) AS [Table]    
      ,IDX.[name] AS [Index] 
      ,US.[user_seeks]
      ,US.[user_scans]
      ,US.[user_lookups]
      ,US.[user_updates]
      ,US.[last_user_seek]
      ,US.[last_user_scan]
      ,US.[last_user_lookup]
      ,US.[last_user_update]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_usage_stats] US
INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] IDX
    ON IDX.[index_id] = US.[index_id]
    AND IDX.[object_id] = US.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats] (DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) AS PHS
    ON PHS.[index_id] = US.[index_id] 
    AND PHS.[object_id] = US.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_db_partition_stats] PRS
    ON PRS.[index_id] = US.[index_id]
    AND PRS.[object_id] = US.[object_id]  
INNER JOIN [sys].[databases] DB
    ON DB.[database_id] = PHS.[database_id]
WHERE [is_primary_key] = 0
    AND US.[user_seeks] = 0
    AND US.[user_scans] = 0
    AND US.[user_lookups] = 0
ORDER BY [Page_Count] DESC
```

The issue is on some database the `[sys].[dm_db_index_usage_stats]` returns more entries for certain indexes. For example:

[image]

As you can see each entry is updated in different times on different date. Could anyone tell why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

From taking a quick look, it's quite possible that you're actually looking at indexes on different databases.

**Alternatively, you could have a partitioned table** as the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187737.aspx) state that sys.dm_db_partition_stats:

> Returns page and row-count information for every partition in the
>   current database.

Take it back to basics, don't use `DB_ID()` and actually use the `database_id` field within `dm_db_index_usage_stats` to join to `sys.databases`.

For now, it would also be best to remove `dm_db_index_physical_stats` (the `INNER JOIN` is not a good way to join to it anyway).

```
SELECT DB.[name] AS [database]
      ,OBJECT_NAME(IDX.[object_id]) AS [Table]    
      ,IDX.[name] AS [Index] 
      ,US.[user_seeks]
      ,US.[user_scans]
      ,US.[user_lookups]
      ,US.[user_updates]
      ,US.[last_user_seek]
      ,US.[last_user_scan]
      ,US.[last_user_lookup]
      ,US.[last_user_update]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_usage_stats] US
INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] IDX
    ON IDX.[index_id] = US.[index_id]
    AND IDX.[object_id] = US.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_db_partition_stats] PRS
    ON PRS.[index_id] = US.[index_id]
    AND PRS.[object_id] = US.[object_id]  
INNER JOIN [sys].[databases] DB
    ON DB.[database_id] = US.database_id
WHERE [is_primary_key] = 0
    AND US.[user_seeks] = 0
    AND US.[user_scans] = 0
    AND US.[user_lookups] = 0
```

Check the database names. Are they all definitely the same database?

Add `PRS.partition_id` to your `SELECT`. Are they all the same partition?

If that looks to be correct, then perhaps `APPLY` the dm_db_index_physical_stats table.

```
SELECT DB.[name]
      ,OBJECT_NAME(IDX.[object_id]) AS [Table]    
      ,IDX.[name] AS [Index] 
      ,US.[user_seeks]
      ,US.[user_scans]
      ,US.[user_lookups]
      ,US.[user_updates]
      ,US.[last_user_seek]
      ,US.[last_user_scan]
      ,US.[last_user_lookup]
      ,US.[last_user_update]
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_usage_stats] US
INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] IDX
    ON IDX.[index_id] = US.[index_id]
    AND IDX.[object_id] = US.[object_id]
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_db_partition_stats] PRS
    ON PRS.[index_id] = US.[index_id]
    AND PRS.[object_id] = US.[object_id]  
INNER JOIN [sys].[databases] DB
    ON DB.[database_id] = US.database_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(US.DATABASE_id, US.OBJECT_ID, US.index_id, NULL, NULL)  AS ddius
WHERE [is_primary_key] = 0
    AND US.[user_seeks] = 0
    AND US.[user_scans] = 0
    AND US.[user_lookups] = 0
ORDER BY ddius.page_count DESC
```